# What's the best way to handle more than 100 conditions in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How can I handle a large number of conditions in a case statement?
...I'm about to write a case statement with about 125 when's.

This is along the lines of what I'm doing now, based on each when I add a node to a Nokogiri XML document, each when has two values that get set in the node, before setting the namespace:

```ruby
case var
when :string
 property_uom_node = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new "test_value", @ixml.doc
    property_uom_node['att'] = "val"
    property_uom_node.namespace = @ixml.doc.root.namespace_definitions.find{|ns| ns.prefix=="dt"}
    property_uom_node
when :integer
 #do something else
when :blue
...
#100 more when statements
...
end
```

I'm not looking for domain specific advice, just if there is a clean way to do this without ending up with a 300 line method.

This is what I ended up doing:

```ruby
lookup = {:lup => ["1","2"], :wup => ["1","2"]}

case param
when lookup.has_key?(param)
  property_uom_node = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new "#{lookup[param][0]}", @ixml.doc
        property_uom_node['att'] = #{lookup[param][1]}
        property_uom_node.namespace = @ixml.doc.root.namespace_definitions.find{|ns| ns.prefix=="dt"}
        property_uom_node
end
```

Comment: Impossible to answer without context. Command pattern?

Comment: What sort of context? Is there a better way to handle 100 or more when conditions inside of a case statement, simple question.

Comment: Yes: don't do it like that. It's only s "simple question" if you don't really care about a good answer.

Comment: I would take any answer to get me started. I'm just not sure what else to ask. Thanks for taking a look though. I'm hoping someone with a more consultative approach comes along to help. I added the code that gets executed in each when.

Comment: why didn't you accept Wayne's answer ?

Comment: @peter, thanks. I'm not sure why. I just accepted it. You are a good citizen of the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many case statements can, and many *should*, be replaced with other structures.  Basically, the idea is to separate the policy -- what you want the code to do -- from the implementation -- how the code does it.

Suppose that your case statement is keyed on a symbol (that is, each of then *when* clauses is a constant symbol):

```
case foo
when :one
  puts 1  
when :two
  puts 2
when :three
  puts 3
else
  puts 'more'
end
```

This can be replaced mostly with a data structure:

```
INTS = {:one => 1, :two => 2}
key = :one
puts INTS[key]    # => 1
```

What if there are two different values, and not just one?  Then make each value its own hash:

```
DOGS = {
  :dog1 => {:name => 'Fido', :color => 'white},
  :dog2 => {:name => 'Spot', :color => 'black spots'},
}
key = :dog2
dog = DOGS[key]
puts "#{dog[:name]}'s color is #{dog[:color]}"
# => "Spot's color is black spots"
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the second case statement only has one case. A hash is a good way to do a lookup(many cases). You might try it like this:

```
if val = lookup[param]
  property_uom_node = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new(val[0], @ixml.doc)
  property_uom_node['att'] = val[1]
  property_uom_node.namespace = @ixml.doc.root.namespace_definitions.find{ |ns| ns.prefix == "dt" }
  property_uom_node # return the node
else
  # not one of our cases
end
```